# the remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure in Azure servicebus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

I am new to Azure service bus.  I tried to make an app that will consume the messages in my servicebus.  But when I run the app, I got this error "the remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure"

Tried a lot of things already about this issue, but I have no luck at all!

How can I possibly fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your certificates on the machine, which connects to the service bus. Some of Microsoft's certificates probably expired.

I had the same issue, caused by uninstalled Windows updates. Some of the updates renew the certificates and that might've caused it.

Something that also worked for finding the certificate, was to open the web browser and browse to the service bus' URL in Azure. It prompted me to install the certificate. It was issued to servicebus.window.net.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this was your issue, but for others with this error, for me it was because I had fiddler activated while running this code.